# Input and variables in batch files

Tags: batch-file, svn

I'm making a batch file to update my svn repository and make copies of its logs, but once I get to the if statements I get "goto was unexpected at this time" and for my echo with the input variable it just says "echo  ECHO is on". I had this working for the most part at one point, but no matter what the input was it would always say the first `input == "y"` block was true.

```
@echo on
set /p UserInput = Are you sure you want to update your repo? 

echo %UserInput% 

if %UserInput% == "y" goto Update

if %UserInput% == "n" goto :EOF


:Update

svn update

Echo Creating the basic log.
svn log > BasicLog.log
:: creates the non-verbose log

Echo Creating the verbose log.
svn log -v > verboseLog.log
::creates the verbose log
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have spaces around `=` in set statements. You've created a variable called `%UserInput %`.

```
set /p UserInput=Are you sure you want to update your repo?
```

And for the second part, you must use quotes on **both** sides of the comparison operator,

```
if /i "%UserInput%"=="y" goto Update
```

The `/i` makes the comparison case-insensitive.

Logic: consider what happens if the input is neither `y` nor `n`

Clue: this is valid:

```
if /i not "%UserInput%"=="y" goto somewhere
```

Comment: Thank you, I also needed to remove the quotations around the y and n in the if statements too.

Comment: @Rave340: Not a good idea. You are better-off quoting both sides in general because you have uncontrolled input which might contain separators. That can cause syntax errors (even quoting both sides isn't bullet-proof.)

Comment: I know I personally use `[` and `]` for string checking, since they're less likely to be used than quotes.